# Change the color of selected menu tab

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, menu

How can I change in my code menu, for change the color of selected menu tab after click? this is my code:

**php**

```
<div class="meniu-item" onclick="$('#content').load('_core/home.php?rand='+Math.random()); window.location.hash = 'home';   ">Home</div>
<div class="meniu-item" onclick="$('#content').load('_core/after-login.php?what=help&rand='+Math.random()); window.location.hash = 'help';  ">Contact</div>
```

**css**

```
.meniu-item {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fdfdfd), color-stop(1, #f1f1f2) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #fdfdfd 5%, #f1f1f2 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fdfdfd', endColorstr='#f1f1f2');
    background-color:#fdfdfd;
    border-right:1px solid #e0e0e0;
    color:#333333;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:4px 0 0 0;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    cursor:pointer;
    height:25px;
    color:#4d4d4d;
    width: 97px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 6px;
    line-height: 2;

}
```

Example:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/MenuControlSelectedItem1/EndProduct1.JPG

Comment: This is not clear. What structure do you want to implemant? Do you want your div to be selectable? Do you want your menu item to be selected depending on the url?

Comment: @Philibobby - after click the button menu need change the color

Comment: So it has to be static? You wont be linking to another page?

Comment: @Philibobby - I want make this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/MenuControlSelectedItem1/EndProduct1.JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
<div data-uri="_core/home.php" class="meniu-item">Home</div>
<div data-uri="_core/after-login.php" class="meniu-item">Contact</div>
```

With the jQuery:

```
$("div.meniu-item").on("click", function()
{
    $('#content').load($(this).data("uri"));
    window.location.hash = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

    // Remove the class 'selected' from all navigation items first.
    $("div.meniu-item").removeClass("selected");

    // Then add it to the one we clicked.
    $(this).addClass("selected");

});
```

Comment: tnx-- and how can change the color after click?

Comment: @user3480332 Make a CSS rule for `div.meniu-item.selected`.

Comment: don't change the color after click... what is wrong?

Comment: the color don't change @Marty

Comment: @user3480332 Is the `selected` class being added? Use your inspector.

Comment: in css the .meniu-item have an background-color and this covers the color button that need to see after clicking.

Comment: how can make for example: the buton home when in I enter the site, already be colored, because now when I enter in the site is not colored, need to click home button

Comment: @user3480332 Simply add the `selected` class to the first item in your navigation.

Comment: how.. not working.. is an jquery with hash site.. I adedd like: <div data-uri="_core/home.php" class="meniu-item" class="selected""><?=$lang['sp2']?></div>